# How to pass multiple value in numberOfItemsSection in Xcode 6 using Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been through this for hours, including google the solution and some tutorial, but I couldn't found it. I'm still new to the Swift and Xcode 6.

I don't know whats wrong with the coding. (Exactly I think I knew).

I want to use property list to attach to the label in my project.

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class TransportCollectionView: UICollectionViewController {


    var trans = Array<String>()
    var labelTrans:AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        //self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("transport", ofType: "plist")
        let labeltrans2 = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

        labelTrans = labeltrans2!

        trans = ["alorgajah3.png", "ayerkeroh3.png", "ayermolek3.png","batuberendam3.png", "bertamulu3.png", "batangmelaka3.png","bukitkatil3.png", "bukitrambai3.png", "jasin3.png","kemterendak3.png", "krubong3.png", "kualalinggi3.png","masjidtanah3.png", "merlimau3.png", "mitc3.png", "muar3.png","pantaikundor3.png", "payaikan3.png", "pengkalankempas3.png","pokokmangga3.png", "pulaugadong3.png", "tampin3.png", "tangkak3.png"]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return trans.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
        let cell : TransportCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as TransportCell

        cell.transImg?.image = UIImage(named: trans[indexPath.row])
        cell.transLabel!.text = toString(labelTrans![indexPath.row]!.objectForKey("name")!)

        return cell
    }
```

the error said

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Yes. I know my coding not assigned any value to the labelTrans. Can somebody help me, on how to assigned multiple value?

Comment: You have to confirm which line the error took place Is it that `cell` was `nil`? Was `transLabel` equal to `nil`? You have to identify _which_ optional was `nil` when it was unwrapped.

Comment: Which line causes the error? Also, when you post your code, please clean it up first; we don't need to see Apple's commented out boilerplate or any methods that only call super, or don't have any code.

Comment: **cell.transLabel!.text = toString(labelTrans![indexPath.row]!.objectForKey("name")!)** . This is the line that cause the error @Rob

Comment: @rdelmar **cell.transLabel!.text = toString(labelTrans![indexPath.row]!.objectForKey("name")!)**. this is the line contain error

Comment: You've got a lot of `!` in there and none of them can be `nil`. So go through those variables, one by one, and identify which is `nil`. Also, rather than hard coding `23` in `numberOfItemsInSection`, you should return the count of elements in the `labelTrans` array.

Comment: @Rob Im sorry..actually I already have try with count of the elements in the `labelTrans` array. But the result is still same as before. If I count the array of `labelTrans` or `trans` the result is same. But I will going through you have suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two places where you are unwrapping an optional that can be nil. To debug that (or better, to avoid these kind of crashes) it's better just to use the `if let` unwrapping pattern.

```swift
// rewrite this:

let labeltrans2 = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

labelTrans = labeltrans2!

// as this:

if let labeltrans2 = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) {
   labelTrans = labeltrans2
}
```

This way, if labeltrans2 is nil, nothing inside the if block gets executed. If labeltrans2 if not nil, the labeltrans2 constant gets created.

You should check that:

```
cell.transLabel
```

it's a valid, connected IBOutlet

Also, this piece of code:

```
 labelTrans![indexPath.row]!.objectForKey("name")!
```

it's very convoluted, just because you defined labelTrans to be of type `AnyObject?`. But it's an NSArray, so if you define it like:

```
    var labelTrans: NSArray<String>?
```

you can do:

```
 if let text = labelTrans[indexPath.row] {
      // use text
 }
```

Side note:

Defining `let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"` outside your class makes no sense: it's then a global constant. You should use this constant inside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
     override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
           let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
           // and actually use it here

           let cell : TransportCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier ,forIndexPath: indexPath) as TransportCell
           ...
```